# Double entry in DHCP lease file

Tags: systemd-networkd, dhclient, dhcpcd

I noticed that my DHCP lease file (`/var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.eth1.leases`) has more than one entry for my external Internet-facing IP interface.

Some of the lease entries have overlapping timeframe.

I'm running ISC DHCP client (`dhclient`) on Debian 9.

What could be the cause?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that both `systemd-networkd` and `dhclient` are running at the same time and that both daemons were operating on the same file.

1. dhclient updated `/var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.eth1.leases`
2. systemd-networkd processed same DHCP RESPONSE packets as well and sent packets of which `dhclient` received as well.

systemd-networkd set its T1 timer much earlier, so it reported 'DHCP lease lost' to `syslog()`, replaced IP address with a different one, leaving dhclientd confused.

If you want ISC DHCP client (and not systemd), then turn off DHCP in systemd by editing `/etc/systemd/network`:

```
   [Network]
   DHCP=no
```

If you want systemd (over ISC DHCP client), then uninstall dhclient package:

```
   apt-get remove isc-dhcp-client
```

== RESOLUTION ==

In my case, Verizon FiOS runs a Juniper Network DHCP server and likes to see dhclient reporting `Wireless_Broadband_Router` as the host-name and domain-name as `home` which is what the Actiontec Cablemodem router does anyway.  They also prefers handle broadcast DHCP REBIND message, and not unicast DHCP REBIND message.

Furthermore, DHCP option isn't supported in `systemd-networkd`, so ISC DHCP remains as king.

Also, posted my entire code base related to `systemd` and ISC DHCP client at [GitHub](https://github.com/egberts/systemd-dhclient).

Comment: I've posted my entire code base in https://github.com/egberts/systemd-dhclient